# How can I calculate Total number of outstanding shares from a SEC 10Q report

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, sec

I'm trying to calculate the total number of outstanding shares from a 10Q SEC repot. I dont see a field for that in the balance sheet. I noticed that there is

> As of November 12, 2020, 7,906,250 shares of Class B common stock,
> par value $0.0001 per share, and 31,625,000 shares of Class A common
> > stock, par value $0.0001 per share, were issued and outstanding.

would  Total number of outstanding shares be total B common stock + total Class A common
stock?

This is the SEC report from which Im trying to calculate total number of shares outstanding https://sec.report/Document/0001104659-20-125118/

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. If there convertible bonds or some other instruments that could turn into shares, then for most intents and purposes, you should be looking for "fully diluted" number - the shares that migh potentially become outstanding in the future, rather than only the shares that are outstanding now.

Comment: @DimitriVulis this is for calculating NAV of a SPAC

Comment: @DimitriVulis https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/nav.asp